# How to create an array with the last column align on the right at the end of the page (using array environment))

Tags: horizontal-alignment, arrays

I would like if possible using array environment, to align the last column of my array to the right and at the end of the page. Something like that:

```
\begin{array}{\textwidth}{l r}
   first column & second column
\end{array}
```

But of course this does not work. Does anyone know how to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need the environment `array`? You can use the environment `tabularx` provided by the package `tabularx`.

Comment: Usually I only write math in my array, so I find it annoying to have to put some '$' in each case of my array. But this is right that I don't absolutly need the array package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\usepackage{array}
```

then

```
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{>{$}l<{$}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}>{$}r<{$}@{}}
...
```

.

will push the last column over to the right, and use math mode as for an array environmen.

Comment: It does flush the array to the right, but I would like only the last column to be flushed on the right

Comment: answer updated for this case